# What do the numbers appended to prototype.js signify in ROR generated html mean

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

When I view the javascript links in my generated HTML it reads prototype.js?1304329463. I'm curious as to what the "?1304329463" means, calls or signifies.

Answer (score 6):

It's a simple **cache-control mechanism**.

If you install a new version of Prototype, that number will change, and the browsers will be sure to download the new version.

(In theory, HTTP headers can be used to control caching, but in the real world there are so many different browsers, caches, proxies etc. that all behave in subtly different ways.  It's easier to simply change the URL of a resource when the resource changes, thus guaranteeing that the new version of the resource will be used.)

Comment: Just to add to what others have said, in this case it's a UNIX timestamp. In the future it will be a checksum (Rails 3.1 uses MD5), with the important difference being that even if the file is resaved, if the content doesn't change then it won't be downloaded again by visitors. It's called fingerprinting and [Rails has a guide explaining why it's used](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care). (Note also their caveats about using a timestamped query string.)

Answer (score 1):

The extra query string that gets appended to your static files is part of Rails way of caching your static files that don't change all that often. The hash that gets appended is sort of a fingerprint. If something in that file changes, then that hash changes.

Check [this](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care) out for a little more info.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a unix timestamp (representing Mon, 02 May 2011 09:44:23 GMT). That could be either the request time or the file creation time. Reason to add a timestamp is to be able to easily force browsers to fetch the file again. If the number sequence changes, it's considered to be a different request and browsers will simply refetch the file. That prevents caching issues when files get changed.